# How to have columns of different sizes using tabularx and make table respect page height?

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, kile

I am using Kile and I am trying to learn how to use `tabularx` to have tables that fit within the width of my pages.

However, I have two big problems:

- I have to use X for column size and therefore cannot set the size of my columns (for example, if I have 4 columns, I want column A to be 10% of the size, and columns B, C and D to have the rest equally distributed).
- Now that my table finally fits within the width of the page, it does not respect the height of the page ...

Now to fix this, I read the documentation and used the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
{%
\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.25\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.25\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.25\hsize}X}\cline{2-4}
\textbf{} & \textbf{Hibernate OGM} & \textbf{EclipseLink NoSQL} & \textbf{DataNucleus}\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Goal}} & Complement JPA with NoSQL, key-value stores & Integrates in the father project main goal of providing a complete persistence solution & Being a standards compliant and efficient JPA and JDO platform\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{NoSQL and Datastores supported}} & Infinispan, EHCache, MongoDB & MongoDB, Oracle NoSQL, Oracle AQ, JMS, XML files & Google Big Table, MongoDB, Cassandra, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, AppEngine/DataStore, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP, NeoDatis, db4o\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Operations supported}} & Object Oriented queries (JP-QL), CRUD of entities, Polymorphic entities, Embeddable objects, Basic types (partial), Unidirectional and Bidirectional relationships (partial), Collections, Hibernate Search queries, JPA and Hibernate ORM API & Object Oriented Queries, Polymorphic entities, Basic types, Unidirectional relationships, Collections, JPA (partial), Complex hierarchical, Indexed hierarchical data, Mapped hierarchical data, CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Subset of JP-QL and Criteria API, Denormalization & CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Relationships (Unidirectional and Bidirectional), Queries for JP-QL, JDOQL and SQL (partial),  Basic types, Joins.\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{No support for}} & Denormalization, Complex joins and aggregations & Joins & Aggregations? (not specified in documentation)\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Future}} & High performance sequence generator, parallel key fetching, support for Map/Reduce, more NoSQL classes, better mixing of NoSQL and RDBMS & ? & JPA2.1 full feature list, Official support for Cassandra, Considering a plugin for REDIS\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Commercial support}} & Red Hat & Oracle (via TopLink) & Supported by DataNucleus team\\\hline
\mc{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Documentation}} & Scattered, inactive forums, official documentation lacking & Bureaucratic forums, information is complete and gathered mainly in the official website & Active forums, acceptable official documentation, but the big advantage comes from user support in form of blogs and posts scattered around the Internet\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
}%
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

However, even though the preamble seems to be correct (for a case with 4 columns, where columns B, C and D should be 6x greater than A) nothing happens.

**What do I exactly want?**
Lets say the total width of the table is 100%. I would like for column A to have 10% of that width, and columns B, C and D to have 30% each one.

I would also like to make this table fit in one page, without extended to extra pages. So no, i cannot use longtable ...

The MWE currently generates something like this:

[image]

The documentation I read can be found here:

- http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/tabularx.pdf

How can I fix my problems?

Comment: You don't need tabularx at all as you know in advance how wide you want each column so you can just use a standard `tabular` and use `p` columns. (tabularx will work but be a lot less efficient) Latex tables are entered by row so are just as high as they need to be, so the height of the page is not consulted at all although like any box, it has to fit on the page when done.

Comment: I dont really know the size of my columns exactly. This was just an example :S As for height, you are telling that I cannot fix it?

Comment: You haven't given an example document and I can't guess what you want to fix from your description. what do you mean by respect height of page? If you mean the table is too long then latex tables don't break over a page unless you use longtable or supertab or similar packages, so just use (say) longtable, you don't need tabularx.

Comment: Alright, I now have more code and an image of the problem. I hope all is clear now !

As for respect height of the page I mean that my table is too long and it ignore the page ending !

Comment: Please always post complete (small) document from \documentclass to \end{document} a fragment using undefined commands such as \word is not useful. why can you not just use longtable?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about not knowing the exact size of the columns. Either you want the size automatically determined (use `c`, `r`, `l`, `X` etc.) or you want to specify them (use `p`) or you want a mix (use a mixture). If you don't want `X` and you don't know how wide they should be, how is LaTeX supposed to figure it out? As suggested above, your question is unclear in large part because you haven't provided a Minimal (non-)Working Example. The code you post should be something people can copy, paste and compile to see the issue for themselves.

Comment: @David: As for longtable -> never heard of it, I will try it out. As for \word,I dont see why you are complaining. I have seen people answering questions using \word as a tag and everyone was happy. Still, I will make a lorem ipsum example, if that helps!

Comment: @cfr: Lets say that the maximum width of the table is 100%. I want column A to have 10% width, and columns B C and D to all have 30% of width each one. Now I am under the strong impression, that the best way to do this is using tabularx with the \hsize code that I provided earlier, as is in the documentation.

Comment: As I said above if you want to specify all the column widths as in the previous column then you do not want tabularx you just want a normal tabular or if you need page breaking, longtable. I'm not complaining about `\word` but if I were to try your example, LaTex would stop at that point with an undefined command error. You should post complete error free document (unless you are demonstrating an error). Neither posting code that doesn't run nor posting an image that is generated by code that hasn't been shown helps anyone to help you.

Comment: One way to fit a table that is too large is to use \resizebox from the graphics or graphix packages.  It will shrink everything.

Comment: So `p{.1\linewidth}*{3}{p{.3\linewidth}}}`. Probably you want to reduce them slightly.

Comment: Added a MWE and did several edits to the question. I hope all is clear now :D

Comment: And now you have answers... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

- Use `p{<width>}` for all columns in a regular `tabular`.
- To do this, create a new length `\tabularlength` and set it to the total width of the tabular. I've used `.975\linewidth` here.
- Then define each of the columns in terms of `\tabularlength` e.g. `p{.1\tabularlength}`.
- To get the first column to behave, dispense with `multicolumn` so that the lines can be broken.
- This means we want hyphenation so load `babel`.
- This isn't quite enough as this doesn't allow hyphenation of the first word in the column. So hyphenate these words by hand using `\-`.
- Use `geometry` to get the page layout right.
- Use `>{\bfseries}` for the first column to avoid having to specify bold on every line.
- We still need one `\multicolumn` for the very first line so we don't get spurious vertical rules.
- Use `\centering` rather than the environment `center` since the latter adds additional spacing which we don't want here.

This actually fits with (a little) room to spare. If the table were bigger, you could consider using `\small` within the `table` environment to set the fontsize a little smaller. Or you could adjust the margins etc. using `geometry`. It is possible to do this for the whole document or, if necessary, a single page.

## The code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel,geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \newlength{\tabularlength}
  \setlength{\tabularlength}{.975\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}p{.1\tabularlength}|*{3}{p{.3\tabularlength}}}
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \textbf{Hibernate OGM} & \textbf{EclipseLink NoSQL} & \textbf{DataNucleus}\\\hline
  Goal & Complement JPA with NoSQL, key-value stores & Integrates in the father project main goal of providing a complete persistence solution & Being a standards compliant and efficient JPA and JDO platform\\\hline
  NoSQL and Datastores supported & Infinispan, EHCache, MongoDB & MongoDB, Oracle NoSQL, Oracle AQ, JMS, XML files & Google Big Table, MongoDB, Cassandra, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, AppEngine/DataStore, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP, NeoDatis, db4o\\\hline
  Oper\-ations supported & Object Oriented queries (JP-QL), CRUD of entities, Polymorphic entities, Embeddable objects, Basic types (partial), Unidirectional and Bidirectional relationships (partial), Collections, Hibernate Search queries, JPA and Hibernate ORM API & Object Oriented Queries, Polymorphic entities, Basic types, Unidirectional relationships, Collections, JPA (partial), Complex hierarchical, Indexed hierarchical data, Mapped hierarchical data, CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Subset of JP-QL and Criteria API, Denormalization & CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Relationships (Unidirectional and Bidirectional), Queries for JP-QL, JDOQL and SQL (partial),  Basic types, Joins.\\\hline
  No support for & Denormalization, Complex joins and aggregations & Joins & Aggregations? (not specified in documentation)\\\hline
  Future & High performance sequence generator, parallel key fetching, support for Map/Reduce, more NoSQL classes, better mixing of NoSQL and RDBMS & ? & JPA2.1 full feature list, Official support for Cassandra, Considering a plugin for REDIS\\\hline
  Com\-mer\-cial support & Red Hat & Oracle (via TopLink) & Supported by DataNucleus team\\\hline
  Docu\-ment\-ation & Scattered, inactive forums, official documentation lacking & Bureaucratic forums, information is complete and gathered mainly in the official website & Active forums, acceptable official documentation, but the big advantage comes from user support in form of blogs and posts scattered around the Internet\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

## The output

[image: Tabular fitted to page]

## An alternative layout

I think you might also want to consider including the tabular in landscape orientation as this might make it easier for people to digest. For example:

[image: Tabular in landscape]

I used an additional formatting directive for the first column in this case, `\raggedright`, to make it look reasonable.

## Code for landscape tabular

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel,geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
  \newlength{\tabularlength}
  \setlength{\tabularlength}{.975\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries\raggedright}p{.1\tabularlength}|*{3}{p{.3\tabularlength}}}
    \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \textbf{Hibernate OGM} & \textbf{EclipseLink NoSQL} & \textbf{DataNucleus}\\\hline
    Goal & Complement JPA with NoSQL, key-value stores & Integrates in the father project main goal of providing a complete persistence solution & Being a standards compliant and efficient JPA and JDO platform\\\hline
    NoSQL and Datastores supported & Infinispan, EHCache, MongoDB & MongoDB, Oracle NoSQL, Oracle AQ, JMS, XML files & Google Big Table, MongoDB, Cassandra, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, AppEngine/DataStore, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP, NeoDatis, db4o\\\hline
    Oper\-ations supported & Object Oriented queries (JP-QL), CRUD of entities, Polymorphic entities, Embeddable objects, Basic types (partial), Unidirectional and Bidirectional relationships (partial), Collections, Hibernate Search queries, JPA and Hibernate ORM API & Object Oriented Queries, Polymorphic entities, Basic types, Unidirectional relationships, Collections, JPA (partial), Complex hierarchical, Indexed hierarchical data, Mapped hierarchical data, CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Subset of JP-QL and Criteria API, Denormalization & CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Relationships (Unidirectional and Bidirectional), Queries for JP-QL, JDOQL and SQL (partial),  Basic types, Joins.\\\hline
    No support for & Denormalization, Complex joins and aggregations & Joins & Aggregations? (not specified in documentation)\\\hline
    Future & High performance sequence generator, parallel key fetching, support for Map/Reduce, more NoSQL classes, better mixing of NoSQL and RDBMS & ? & JPA2.1 full feature list, Official support for Cassandra, Considering a plugin for REDIS\\\hline
    Com\-mer\-cial support & Red Hat & Oracle (via TopLink) & Supported by DataNucleus team\\\hline
    Docu\-ment\-ation & Scattered, inactive forums, official documentation lacking & Bureaucratic forums, information is complete and gathered mainly in the official website & Active forums, acceptable official documentation, but the big advantage comes from user support in form of blogs and posts scattered around the Internet\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

## Centred columns & vertical rules

As noted by Flame_Phoenix in the comments, `m{<width>}` gives a column of specified width which is centred vertically. This specifier requires the `array` package.

Adding a vertical rule before 'Hibernate OGM' is just a question of adjusting the `\multicolumn` for the first entry of the tabular. Centring all cells horizontally, as well as vertically, can be done by adding `>{\centering}` in the tabular configuration. However, this gets a bit tedious and is harder to adjust consistently. A better solution uses the ability of `array` to define a new column type.

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering}m{.3\tabularlength}}
```

Because my example shows the layout for both portrait and landscape, I also need to pull the addition of `\tabularlength` out of the `tabular` environments so I'm not trying to define an already defined length.

```
\newlength{\tabularlength}
```

The `m` column type treats `\\` as a new line within the column rather than the end of the row. I therefore need to replace `\\\hline` with `\tabularnewline\hline`.

Finally, I've added a vertical rule on the far right for neatness.

### The code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel,geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newlength{\tabularlength}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering}m{.3\tabularlength}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \setlength{\tabularlength}{.975\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\bfseries}m{.1\tabularlength}|*{3}{M}|}
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \textbf{Hibernate OGM} & \textbf{EclipseLink NoSQL} & \textbf{DataNucleus}\tabularnewline\hline
  Goal & Complement JPA with NoSQL, key-value stores & Integrates in the father project main goal of providing a complete persistence solution & Being a standards compliant and efficient JPA and JDO platform\tabularnewline\hline
  NoSQL and Datastores supported & Infinispan, EHCache, MongoDB & MongoDB, Oracle NoSQL, Oracle AQ, JMS, XML files & Google Big Table, MongoDB, Cassandra, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, AppEngine/DataStore, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP, NeoDatis, db4o\tabularnewline\hline
  Oper\-ations supported & Object Oriented queries (JP-QL), CRUD of entities, Polymorphic entities, Embeddable objects, Basic types (partial), Unidirectional and Bidirectional relationships (partial), Collections, Hibernate Search queries, JPA and Hibernate ORM API & Object Oriented Queries, Polymorphic entities, Basic types, Unidirectional relationships, Collections, JPA (partial), Complex hierarchical, Indexed hierarchical data, Mapped hierarchical data, CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Subset of JP-QL and Criteria API, Denormalization & CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Relationships (Unidirectional and Bidirectional), Queries for JP-QL, JDOQL and SQL (partial),  Basic types, Joins.\tabularnewline\hline
  No support for & Denormalization, Complex joins and aggregations & Joins & Aggregations? (not specified in documentation)\tabularnewline\hline
  Future & High performance sequence generator, parallel key fetching, support for Map/Reduce, more NoSQL classes, better mixing of NoSQL and RDBMS & ? & JPA2.1 full feature list, Official support for Cassandra, Considering a plugin for REDIS\tabularnewline\hline
  Com\-mer\-cial support & Red Hat & Oracle (via TopLink) & Supported by DataNucleus team\tabularnewline\hline
  Docu\-ment\-ation & Scattered, inactive forums, official documentation lacking & Bureaucratic forums, information is complete and gathered mainly in the official website & Active forums, acceptable official documentation, but the big advantage comes from user support in form of blogs and posts scattered around the Internet\tabularnewline\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
  \setlength{\tabularlength}{.975\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries\centering}m{.1\tabularlength}|*{3}{M}|}
    \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \textbf{Hibernate OGM} & \textbf{EclipseLink NoSQL} & \textbf{DataNucleus}\tabularnewline\hline
    Goal & Complement JPA with NoSQL, key-value stores & Integrates in the father project main goal of providing a complete persistence solution & Being a standards compliant and efficient JPA and JDO platform\tabularnewline\hline
    NoSQL and Datastores supported & Infinispan, EHCache, MongoDB & MongoDB, Oracle NoSQL, Oracle AQ, JMS, XML files & Google Big Table, MongoDB, Cassandra, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, AppEngine/DataStore, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP, NeoDatis, db4o\tabularnewline\hline
    Operations supported & Object Oriented queries (JP-QL), CRUD of entities, Polymorphic entities, Embeddable objects, Basic types (partial), Unidirectional and Bidirectional relationships (partial), Collections, Hibernate Search queries, JPA and Hibernate ORM API & Object Oriented Queries, Polymorphic entities, Basic types, Unidirectional relationships, Collections, JPA (partial), Complex hierarchical, Indexed hierarchical data, Mapped hierarchical data, CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Subset of JP-QL and Criteria API, Denormalization & CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Relationships (Unidirectional and Bidirectional), Queries for JP-QL, JDOQL and SQL (partial),  Basic types, Joins.\tabularnewline\hline
    No support for & Denormalization, Complex joins and aggregations & Joins & Aggregations? (not specified in documentation)\tabularnewline\hline
    Future & High performance sequence generator, parallel key fetching, support for Map/Reduce, more NoSQL classes, better mixing of NoSQL and RDBMS & ? & JPA2.1 full feature list, Official support for Cassandra, Considering a plugin for REDIS\tabularnewline\hline
    Commercial support & Red Hat & Oracle (via TopLink) & Supported by DataNucleus team\tabularnewline\hline
    Document\-ation & Scattered, inactive forums, official documentation lacking & Bureaucratic forums, information is complete and gathered mainly in the official website & Active forums, acceptable official documentation, but the big advantage comes from user support in form of blogs and posts scattered around the Internet\tabularnewline\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

### The Output

[image: All centred tabular]

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I have been playing around with it and I had a couple of questions: I change the `p` to `m` so everything would be aligned to the center vertically. But how do I also align it to the center horizontally using `m` and without having to type `\centering` in every cell?
And also, how can I add a `|` at the start of the "Hibernate OGM" column? There is that little piece currently missing !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I based the rules and alignment on your original. To get a vertical rule before 'Hibernate OGM' just replace `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` with `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}`. What do you want centred horizontally exactly? The contents of every cell or only some of them?

Comment: ya I know, my original example is quite messy because I am still new. As for horizontally centering content, I think it would look more coherent to have all cells horizontally centered. If I am going to center the very small ones, I may as well center the big ones!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix See the additional section I've added to my answer showing how to centre everything and add additional vertical rules.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Your main error was the multicolumn which was replacing the specified width column by a natural width `l` column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering\small
\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr\textwidth-6\tabcolsep\relax}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\hspace*{0pt}\bfseries}p{.1\dimen0}*3{p{.3\dimen0}}}
 & \textbf{Hibernate OGM} & \textbf{EclipseLink NoSQL} & \textbf{DataNucleus}\\\hline
Goal & Complement JPA with NoSQL, key-value stores & Integrates in the father project main goal of providing a complete persistence solution & Being a standards compliant and efficient JPA and JDO platform\\\hline
NoSQL and Datastores supported & Infinispan, EHCache, MongoDB & MongoDB, Oracle NoSQL, Oracle AQ, JMS, XML files & Google Big Table, MongoDB, Cassandra, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, AppEngine/DataStore, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP, NeoDatis, db4o\\\hline
Operations supported & Object Oriented queries (JP-QL), CRUD of entities, Polymorphic entities, Embeddable objects, Basic types (partial), Unidirectional and Bidirectional relationships (partial), Collections, Hibernate Search queries, JPA and Hibernate ORM API & Object Oriented Queries, Polymorphic entities, Basic types, Unidirectional relationships, Collections, JPA (partial), Complex hierarchical, Indexed hierarchical data, Mapped hierarchical data, CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Subset of JP-QL and Criteria API, Denormalization & CRUD operations, Embedded objects and collections, Inheritance, Relationships (Unidirectional and Bidirectional), Queries for JP-QL, JDOQL and SQL (partial),  Basic types, Joins.\\\hline
No support for & Denormalization, Complex joins and aggregations & Joins & Aggregations? (not specified in documentation)\\\hline
Future & High performance sequence generator, parallel key fetching, support for Map/Reduce, more NoSQL classes, better mixing of NoSQL and RDBMS & ? & JPA2.1 full feature list, Official support for Cassandra, Considering a plugin for REDIS\\\hline
Commercial support & Red Hat & Oracle (via TopLink) & Supported by DataNucleus team\\\hline
Documentation & Scattered, inactive forums, official documentation lacking & Bureaucratic forums, information is complete and gathered mainly in the official website & Active forums, acceptable official documentation, but the big advantage comes from user support in form of blogs and posts scattered around the Internet\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```